# Irregular slider in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, slider, data-visualization

I'm trying to build a slider in D3. I found a library for this https://github.com/johnwalley/d3-simple-slider which is perfect for the regular slider.

However, I need to slide by steps among irregularly spaced dates : [2002,2005,2012,2029] for example.

Do I need to build the slider by myself? Or do you know any other way?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin you have chosen can work. See the example below. You need to add some customization.

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-simple-slider"></script>

<p id="value"></p>
<div id="slider"></div>

<script>

  var data = [2002,2005,2012,2029];
  var slider = d3
    .sliderHorizontal()
    .min(d3.min(data))
    .max(d3.max(data))
    .width(500)
    .displayValue(false)
    .on('onchange', val => {
      d3.select('#value').text(val);
    });
    
    slider.tickValues(data)
          .marks(data);

  d3.select('#slider')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 600)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(30,30)')
    .call(slider);
</script>
```